# In laravel how to seed existing databse using array?

Tags: laravel, database, laravel-seeding

I want to seed existing database in my application.
here is db with data in it: [image]

I made array in seeder and now I want to assign those values to my fields with one loop I guess;

> This is migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->char('maker');
            $table->integer('model')->unique();
            $table->string('type');

        });
    }
```

And here is my seeder, I tried something but it isn't working. it says "Undefined array key "A""

```
public function run()
    {
        $array = ['A',  1232,   'PC',
                'A',    1233,   'PC',
                'A',    1276,   'Printer',
                'A',    1298,   'Laptop',
                'A',    1401,   'Printer',
                'A',    1408,   'Printer',
                'A',    1752,   'Laptop',
                'B',    1121,   'PC',
                'B',    1750,   'Laptop',
                'C',    1321,   'Laptop',
                'D',    1288,   'Printer',
                'D',    1433,   'Printer',
                'E',    1260,   'PC',
                'E',    1434,   'Printer',
                'E',    2112,   'PC',
                'E',    2113,   'PC'
        ];

        foreach ($array as $key => $item){

            Product::create([
                'maker' => $array[$item],
                'model' => $array[$item],
                'type' => $array[$item]
            ]);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function for insert all data

```
for($i=0;i<size_of($array);$i++){
    if(($i%3)==0){
     DB::table('products')->insert([
        'maker' =>$array[$i],
        'model' => $array[$i+1],
        'type' => $array[$i+2]
    ]);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: had to change size_of with count but it worked. Thank you!

Comment: In my humble opinion you need function  Product::create([]) better for you 
case you this function add id automatic